# CMFCRibbonStatusBar and menu prompts

Tags: mfc

I have a VS2015 application based around a Ribbon bar with numerous context menu's.  The issue is how do I get the legacy menu item prompts to route the status bar derived from CMFCRibbonStatusBar.

Pre Ribbon bar these prompts were transparently mapped to CMFCStatusBar.  Advice on how to activate/re-establish this facility under the Ribbon Bar environment would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know, but I can advice you to put a breakpoint on `CFrameWnd::GetMessageString` and try to follow the code.

Comment: CFrameWnd::GetMessageString() provided good advice and showed the messages being picked up within MFC but not displayed.  Consequently reverted CMFCRibbonStatusBar to CMFCStatusBar and all worked fine again.

Comment: I think you would need to implement the `SetWindowText` method on your "status bar derived from CMFCRibbonStatusBar" class.

Comment: See my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/a/42957422/383779